# jquery Help with getting Id of table row

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am doing an AJAX request with Jquery and PHP what I am doing is looping through an array and producing a table, each loop a new is created and an id is given to it, when they click the read me link the ajax and some more content is returned, on clicking read more I want the associated table row to be removed from the table is this possible, you can see my attempt so far below.

```
<div id="new" class="tabdiv">
    <table>
    <?php
        $colours = array("#f9f9f9", "#f3f3f3"); $count = 0;
        if(isset($newSuggestions)) {
            foreach($newSuggestions as $row) {
                if($row['commentRead'] == 0) {
    ?>
                    <tr id="<?=$row['thoughtId'];?>" bgcolor="<?php echo $colours[$count++ % count($colours)];?>">
    <?php
                        echo "<td>".substr($row['thought'], 0,50)."...</td>";
                        echo "<td class='read'><a href='".base_url()."thought/readSuggestion/".$row['thoughtId']."' class='readMore'>Read More</a>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "You have no new suggestions";
            }
    ?>
    </table>

$('a.readMore').click(function(){
            $('#readMore').fadeIn(500);
            var url = $('a.readMore').attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                url : url,
                type : "POST",
                success : function(html) {
                    $('#readMore').html(html)
                },
                complete : function() {
                    $('tr').remove()
                } 
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the id of the row like this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().attr("id")
```

`$(this)` wraps the a element, the first parent gets the td and the next one the tr. Call this inside the click callback. Make sure that the id starts with a letter; it is not allowed to start a number. To delete it, define a variable:

```
var row = $(this).parent().parent();
```

You can then delete it at the callbacks:

```
row.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

As kgiannakakis points out you'll need a reference to the element that was clicked.
To find out what went wrong, consider the following lines of your code:

```
$('a.readMore').click(function(){
  var url = $('a.readMore').attr('href');
  ...
  return  false;
});
```

What you do here is add an event handler to all a elements with a readMore class.
When the link is clicked you again select all a elements with a readMore class and retreive the href attribute from the first matched element.
What you want to do is get the attribute from the element that was clicked.

```
$('a.readMore').click(function(){
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  ...
  return  false;
});
```

The same problem occurs in the success and complete handlers of your ajax request, note that you can't use this in the success/complete handlers because it will probably point to another object so you need to store it in a var before calling the ajax function.